# "This file is currently not available for use on this computer"

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am hoping someone has had this issue before and can help me resolve. I was working on a company project. I had just finished up and needed to publish my project to the server. When trying to publish, I got the error "This file is currently not available for use on this computer."

So then I tried to open one of the .cs files of the solution, and the error occurred again from trying to open the file. So I tried to grab the latest version from TFS thinking it would give me whichever file is missing, but when I click "Get Latest Version" on the project, the error message pops up there too.

I thought surely I will be able to delete the project locally and then remap it, but I can't even delete the project off my computer, as the error message pops up halfway through deletion. When it occurs there, however, I do get "Error 0x800710FE: This file is currently not available for use on this computer."

Also have tried deleting offline cached files through Control Panel > Sync Center > Manage Offline Files > Disk Usage > Delete temp files

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-US/6b921b88-87e8-4b24-b49c-45b111624050/windows-7-offline-cache-corrupt

Comment: Thanks. I had seen that article but it did not solve the problem. The folder is still there, still cant delete.

Comment: Please include in your question what you have tried. The error is not related to TFS, but to Windows Offline files.

Comment: Aside from the steps in that article, and trying to get latest version, do remappings, and delete files locally, that is all I have tried.

Comment: Again, please include everything you have tried _in your question_. See also [KB 942974](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942974).

Answer (score 1):

I got this error for a small, test solution that was not using TFS. The default file location is the documents folder, which in my environment is synced using the Sync Center. I moved all of the solution files to a new local folder that was not included in Sync operations and the error went away.

Conclusion: storing VS files in a folder managed by Sync Center is likely a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when trying to save an excel file served from a webpage. 
The solution for me was to save it under a different filename. Possibly because I previously had a file with the same name open in excel.