# Unknown build error, 'This file is currently not available for use on this computer. '

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm at a complete loss as to what to do. Every time I try to build my project in Visual Studio 2015 I get an error saying,

> Unknown build error, 'This file is currently not available for use on this computer.'

It does not name the file nor give me any clues whatsoever as to what the issue is. I've deleted my `obj` and `bin` folders to no effect. I've restored a backup from earlier this morning and it also happens in this project as well.

Has anyone come across this problem before?

Comment: Just a random thought: Are you using any kind of Source Control (TFS, Git) or Sync (DropBox, OneDrive)? May be a locked file.

Comment: Related: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33136434/this-file-is-currently-not-available-for-use-on-this-computer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33136434/this-file-is-currently-not-available-for-use-on-this-computer) - this error message seems to refer to "Offline storage" or DFS

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer nothing like that at all it is all local. Although that question is related in the sense of the error message I can still do all the things listed there that he couldn't.

Comment: Does this happen for all projects, or just a specific one? Does that project build on a colleague's computer? Have you tried using something like [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see if it will tell you what file access is failing? What do you mean by _restored a backup_? (a backup of what?)

Comment: @RichardEverett completely restoring a backup of my entire Visual Studio folder fixed this issue, weird. Thomas, Is that really necessary?

Comment: Yes. Please ask a different question so we better understand what you really want to know. Do you want to know what it means or know how to find the root cause or know how to fix it or know where to report it as a bug?

Answer (score 1):

You can troubleshoot missing file problems with [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx).

1. Set a filter on the process that causes the issue.
2. Reproduce the issue
3. Save the result as XML
4. Get [ProcMon Log Analyzer](http://debugging.wellisolutions.de/procmonanalyzer/) - Disclaimer: I'm the author of the tool
5. Analyze the XML

Why do it like that?

When loading DLLs, Windows may look in the current directory first, then in PATH and then in Windows system32 directory. All the unsuccessful accesses will be traced, even if the DLL is finally found.

ProcMon Log Analyzer will find out whether the loading of a file was finally successful or not and how many attempts it took.